# Java: everything in a class is static - is this reasonable?

Tags: java

I 'm just wondering if what I'm doing is somehow poor design.

I have a ArrayList of things. I need this list to always exist. I only need to have one of these lists. I also have some methods to interact with this list. Thusly, I made everything static.

The thing is that since all of these things are tucked away into a single class, literally everything in that class is declared as static. Which seems a bit odd, because it's like I want to have the entire class be static.

The facts that Java doesn't allow me to make an entire class static and that I was taught to minimize static methods in my code are setting off a few alarm bells in my head, but I honestly can't see any rational reason why what I'm doing won't work well.

EDIT: A bit more about the program and why I decided to do what I did, because I guess that would help (and it was asked, of course).

The center of the program are two databases, one for items and another for characters.
Characters need to have temporary posession of items, but all items must be able to be listed at all times.

I decided I would have an arraylist of items, each item having a boolean marking it available or not available (making it easy to display both all items and available items). Each character would have their own, smaller arraylist of items, to which I would add duplicates of the item from the database.

To be able to access the database from other classes (this is where I started with the idea), I considered my easiest option to simply make the large arraylist static because there is no situation where I need it to not exist and there is no situation where I need more than one. Of course, as I made the list static, I needed to make all of the basic methods of interacting with it static as well.

I'm pretty sure there are better ways of doing what I'm trying to do, but I'm just a beginner practising.

EDIT2: Oh, and the list of items will be added to, removed from, and it's items modified while the program runs. Another effect of the characters receiving copies of items is that their own items will remain the same as long as they have them.

Comment: Everything in `Math`, `Objects`, or `Arrays` is static, so there's nothing inherently wrong with it. You could try looking up the singleton pattern and seeing if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Singleton is often considered an anti-pattern, something to strive to avoid.

Comment: It's unusual, but there's nothing wrong with it, as nullptr has pointed out. In fact, I think people try to hard sometimes to make something object-oriented that doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your update, you've arrived at the classic "It's a singleton!" moment, after which someone should point out to you that "It's (almost) never a singleton!". Instead, this should be a normal, non-static, non-singleton class, and the rest of the application should be written to always use a single instance of it. The fact that your application only needs a single instance of a thing doesn't make that thing a singleton. You'd benefit from reading several of the articles that turn up from Google searches for ["why is singleton evil"](https://www.google.com/search?q=why%20is%20singleton%20evil) and ["singleton antipattern"](https://www.google.com/search?q=singleton%20antipattern).

It's also sounding like you might be talking about shared mutable state, which is a whole other (giant) can of worms that you don't want to get into without some careful consideration.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like there's plenty of dislike for the singleton class. I can't say I _exactly_ understand it all, but I don't see why I should avoid generally accepted good form. The thing is, though, I'm not sure how I would go around using a single instance. I couldn't quite figure out how to make a method in the Character class grab an Item from the list of items because Java wouldn't allow me to iterate if the list wasn't static (I originally did have it constructed elsewhere).

Comment: What's this "good form" you speak of? Singletons aren't good form, and neither are stateful, static classes. For Character instances getting access to Item info, you'd have something that ensures all Characters are given an appropriate Item to work from. That points you in the direction of dependency injection, which has a major impact on testability. The above referenced articles expound on these and other points in great detail.

Comment: I meant that avoiding singletons is good form and I would like to do that.

Comment: I think I'll just avoid iterating the list in a separate class. This would mean that I will have to break up the method into two separate ones in the list class where it would find items in the list and return their data; and in the Character class where a new Item class will be created from this returned data. I, uh, I'm not sure that's much better than a singleton class, though.

Comment: Not sure I follow that, but how about if a Character took an Item in as a constructor argument? Then you're correctly indicating that the one has a dependency on the other, and whoever tries to create a Character also becomes responsible for managing Items correctly. (I also think your names are a little confusing. Isn't this "Item" thing more of an "ItemLoader"?)

Comment: Yes, I think that's roughly what I had in mind. Thanks for the help! I'll pick this one as the accepted answer then. (and I think "Item" is accurate as it's just a name and some stats as integers; everything is text-based)

Answer (score 4):

If you need exactly one list of  `Thing`s in your system, you need to ask yourself what these things are. Are they items that can be configured before each run?  Are they things that will change as the user executes the program?  Perhaps these things should be stored as records in a database, even a lightweight in-memory one like Apache Derby or a NoSQL database.

Even if you genuinely have a fixed set of items, you should consider using a dependency injection system and vending the list in singleton scope instead of using a hardwired singleton. This way you can replace the list in your test classes by changing the configuration.

If you find that last confusing, consider this instead.  Suppose you had a class that handles `Things`, say by keeping a static list of them inside it.  Something like:

```
public class ThingCatalog {
    private static final List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<>();
    public ThingCatalog() {
        // initialize list of things.
    }
    public List<Thing> getThings() {
        return things;
    }
    public Thing getThingWithId(int id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, you could make `ThingCatalog` a singleton class; you've seen how to do it.  Make the constructor private, and create a static `getInstance` method.  You'd be tempted to write

```
public class TreasureGenerator {
    private ThingCatalog things = ThingCatalog.getInstance();
    // ...
}
```

What happens if you want write unit test for method in this class that don't use things?  You don't need the things, so you don't really need ThingCatalog at all.  Unforunately, you're stuck with it.

You can start to fix this by giving TreasureGenerator a setThingCatalog method:

```
public void setThingCatalog(ThingCatalog things) {
   this.things = things;
}
```

Of course, you only have one ThingCatalog, so that doesn't help much.  But if you had an interface that ThingCatalog could implement:

```
public interface ThingVendor {
    List<Thing> getThings();
    Thing getThingById(int id);
}
```

and all your classes used ThingVendor instead of ThingCatalog, you could replace it in your tests.

Here's a more business-like example.  You are writing a financial program, and you need have it print today's date on checks.  Typical is to write code like:

```
String recipient = ...;
String accountOwner = ...;
BigDecimal amount = ...;
String accountNumber = ...;
Date today = new Date();
printCheck(...);
```

Now, somebody asks you "Can your program handle leap days correctly?"  Fourteen years ago, the question might have been about  Y2K.  How would you test this?  You're stuck with *today* in this method.

Instead, you write an interface called `DateGenerator`:

```
public interface DateGenerator {
    Date today();
}

public class TodayGenerator implements DateGenerator {
    public Date today() { return new Date(); }
}

public class LeapDayGenerator implements DateGenerator {
    public Date today() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2016, FEBRUARY, 29); // assume static imports;
        return cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

Your class would have a setDateGenerator method, and you'd use TodayGenerator normally.  In your leap day test, you'd use the LeapDayGenerator.

A dependency injection system automates these processes.  What you will learn with experience if you stay with computing is that objects should not know how to configure themselves.  Other parts of the project should glue objects together.

Comment: I wanted to do everything in Java for practice, though I realized very quickly that a lot of things would be much easier with SQL. The items themselves aren't fixed (the list can be added to and removed from while the progam runs). I'm sorry, but as a beginner, "a dependency injection system and vending the list in singleton scope instead of using a hardwired singleton" just sounds like technobabble. :P I just learned what a singleton is earlier in this same thread.

Comment: Sorry--sometimes I misjudge the level of the writer.  I'll edit my post to make a more appropriate suggestion.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a really nice meaty edit, great stuff for what I'm trying to do; thanks a lot!

Comment: The ThingCatalog class isn't a very good one; adapt it for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say but I fear that yours may be a bad plan, and that you may need to re-design your program. Your class has a state, and this suggests to me that it shouldn't be static.

Things that should be static:

- Constants
- Utility methods
- Fields that belong to the class and not the instance.

Consider giving us more information about your program structure so that we can give a more precise answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updates explaining a bit more about the program. What do you mean by "Your class has a state"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to agree that your design sounds suboptimal.  Many of your goals appear to be those which are typical of procedural, rather than object-oriented, programming.

If you find that your project has a strong reliance upon static mutable data, then you should ask yourself why you need so much global data.